# Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, rest, generics, function-overloading

Есть два метода:

```
public TE Post<T,TE>(IRestRequest request, T obj) where T : class, new() where TE : class, new()

public TE Post<T, TE>(IRestRequest request, TE entity) where T : class, new() where TE : IEntityResponse<T>, new()
```

И вызов:

```
Put<T, T>(request, obj);
```

На моей машине код билдится без проблем, компилятор отличает эти перегрузки. Два человека стянули себе код и проект у них не билдится с ошибкой:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'BCRestClient.Post(IRestRequest, T)' and
>   'BCRestClient.Post(IRestRequest, TE)'

В чем может быть разница в наших средах, что у меня проблем нет, а у ребят - есть? Не могу понять  в какую сторону копать. Конечно, можно слить эти методы, это решит проблему, но интересно почему она в принципе могла возникнуть.

Comment: версии компиляторов у вас одинаковые?

Comment: Настройки ошибок/предупредупреждений одинаковые?

Comment: Что если добавить явный каст к IEntityResponse, если на нём появляется ошибка?

Comment: Какой из методов должен быть вызван в этой строчке? `IEntityResponse<int> foo = null; Post<IEntityResponse<int>, IEntityResponse<int>>(null, foo);`

Comment: @tym32167 скорее всего типизация неявная, в общем случае уходит в первый метод.

Comment: @Monk мне выдает ошибку из вопроса

Comment: А если создать класс реализующий интерфейс, то уже всё ок: `EntityResponse<int> foo = null; Post<EntityResponse<int>, EntityResponse<int>>(null, foo);`, по крайней мере у меня, т.к. ругается только на то, что нет конструктора.

Comment: @Monk каст к IEntityResponse не нужен, вызов второй перегрузки ошибок не выдает. Ошибка появляется при попытке обратиться к первому методу, где оба параметра типа - не интерфейсы

Comment: @Monk точно такая же [проблема с классом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o36eX.png)

Comment: Проблема была в разных версиях Visual Studio. У меня 19 и на ней все компилится, на 15 и 17 не компилится. Вот такие дела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должен помочь следующий совет из документации ([Compiler error CS0121](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0121)):

> Use named arguments.

```cs
Put<T, T>(request: request, entity: obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы с компиляцией подобного типа перегрузок нет на 19 версии Visual Studio. На более младших версиях - код не компилируется с ошибкой.